# How to mask and unmask specific row in datagridview using toggle button in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I password mask and unmask the text in the specific row in datagridview using toggle button. for example 1st row?

```
      private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {



       if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Value != null)
        {
            e.Value = new String('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
        }


    }
```

im done with masking but how can i change it back to original text after pressing toggle button?

Comment: Please post you [mcve] and explain what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Esko I want to set the text to asterisk(*) in specific row in datagridview

Comment: And set it back to original after pressing toggle button

Comment: I know, but you need to show some effort to us, this is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Esko my bad sir :( I posted my codes